# Get InputStream from Apache's POI Workbook

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, inputstream

Is there a way to obtain `InputStream` of Apache's POI Workbook?

I need it for piping to another `OutputStream`, however I'm unable to find such method (If it exists).

If it doesn't, any tips on alternative ways to obtain it?

Comment: Why not to use its `write` method? (http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#write(java.io.OutputStream))

Comment: I am aware of that method, however, I have some requirements such that I need an input stream.

Comment: Write to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, grab the byte array from that when writing is complete, then pass that to a `ByteArrayInputStream` ?

Comment: Yeah, I though of that as an alternative

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a several ways to solve this:

1. You can use standard java `PipetInputStream` and `PipedOutputStream`. But you have to create different thread for using `PipedInputStream` (as described in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html)
2. You can write the content to `ByteArrayOutputStream`, and then you can use resulting byte array via `ByteArrayInputStream`. This can be done sequentially in one thread.

Comment: Yeah, I though of #2 as an alternative, guess that's gonna be it.

Answer (score 17):

Here's how to implement #2 of Alexander Tokarev's answer (i.e get Inputstream from a workbook):

```
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        workbook.write(bos);
        byte[] barray = bos.toByteArray();
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(barray);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java

here they are converting the whole sheet to csv file, using inputstream which they got from XLSX file.

```
ReadOnlySharedStringsTable strings = new ReadOnlySharedStringsTable(this.xlsxPackage);
        XSSFReader xssfReader = new XSSFReader(this.xlsxPackage);
        StylesTable styles = xssfReader.getStylesTable();
        XSSFReader.SheetIterator iter = (XSSFReader.SheetIterator) xssfReader.getSheetsData();
        int index = 0;
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            InputStream stream = iter.next();
            String sheetName = iter.getSheetName();
            this.output.println();
            this.output.println(sheetName + " [index=" + index + "]:");
            processSheet(styles, strings, new SheetToCSV(), stream);
            stream.close();
            ++index;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend XSSFWorkbook, save the File or InputStream object from constructor and them get it back with some method like getInputStream()